# Converting a string to variable of a wrapper class on runtime for achieving multiple search criteria like in reports

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, custom-report-type

My target is to place a multiple filters on Visual force page to filter data just like in reports.This data is coming from external system on a rest call.I was storing this data in a list of wrapper class and displaying it back.Presently it is showing raw data .I have to give filtering option too

[image: Presently it is showing raw data .I have to give filtering option too]

For this i am reading field names and their values and operator in apex class string fields.But i was wondering how to dofiltering using if condition.

sampel wrapper class

```
  public class PatientRecordsWrapp{
    public String BlueStarID{get;set;}
    public String FirstName{get;set;}
    public String LastName{get;set;}
    public String ProviderName{get;set;}
   public PatientRecordsWrapp(){
    }
}
```

In general i want to filter it as

```
 if(PatientRecordsWrapp.FirstName== searchValVariable1 && PatientRecordsWrapp.BlueStarID==searchValVariable1 ){
   // add this wrapper class to search list
}
```

here i am able to pass values dynamically,but i want to pass the fields and operator also in dynamic way

like

```
String searchid1='FirstNameme or BlueStarID or LastName';
      String searchid2='FirstNameme or BlueStarID or LastName';
      String operator='And / OR';
i will read these variable from visual force page.
```

So i want to create a dynamic conditional statement like

```
 if(PatientRecordsWrapp+'searchid1'== searchValVariable1  + operator  + PatientRecordsWrapp'searchid2'==searchValVariable1 ){
       // add this wrapper class to search list
    }
```

this should result in like if user selects FirstName , BlueStarID and AND operator in page as shown in picture.The condition should be generated like

```
  if(PatientRecordsWrapp.FirstName== searchValVariable1 && PatientRecordsWrapp.BlueStarID==searchValVariable1 ){
       // add this wrapper class to search list
    }
```

Is there any chance to achieve this.I am eagerly waiting for ideas. And there is no chance of SOQL because the data will come on fly.So only conditional statements seems to be best option for me.

Comment: Seems pretty simple with just those two fields to be able to build a dynamic query. Have you read up on that?

Comment: I already mentioned I am not going to save anything in any object.. I was parsing json to list of wrapper classes.. And trying to loop on the list.. So there is no chance of having any dynamic queries

Comment: Then your only way to do this is to cycle thought the result and compare to the filters.

Comment: @Eric thanks just now I was trying for this approach using map data structure